# Running into Java Heap Size issues with OpenTripPlanner

Tags: java, opentripplanner

I'm trying to load up OpenTripPlanner on my PC and utilize it.

I get everything set to run, then it gets about two minutes into the OSM file nad icks out "exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space", followed by "at", then listing a whole mess of places it's out of memory.

I've tried -Xmxing every file size it will allow, to no avail.

(I'm running Win8.1 with 16gb RAM).

I don't have access to a shell running Java to use this with, so hopefully I'll be able to make my system work.

Comment: Can you provide the code?

Comment: It takes a lot of memory, especially if you have a large OSM file. I usually use -Xmx8G.